# How do I access ID/name values in an array of JSON object using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an array of json objects with the following content:

```
[
 {
  "id":"4d631c00-81b6-11e5-a433-eb40dfe04266",
  "name":"a",
  "parent":"123",
  "main_organisation":"#",
  "active":1,
  "contact_person":"aa",
  "resp_consultant":"a",
  "address_1":"a",
  "goals":null,
  "address_2":"a",
  "org_nr":"a",
  "zip":"a",
  "city":"aa",
  "country":"a",
  "www":"a",
  "email":"aa",
  "phone":"a",
  "misc":"aa",
  "subscription":0,
  "address_visit":"a"
 }
 {
  ...etc
 }
]
```

I also want to put the id and name values in a list, I would be so happy if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1):

A resarch in google have been helpful...

Please have a look at newtosoft : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You have all the samples to do what you want with your json array.

Comment: Don't answer in an answer. Write a comment instead.